# Use fs to check if something in another folder exists in node.js

Tags: node.js

- Folder1

  - file1.js
- Folder2

  - file2.js

I want to check if `file2.js` exists, from `file1.js` using fs (they're in different folders)

I haven't been able to find a way I can do this, without listing the whole directory of `file2.js`.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fs.existsSync`:

**In you file1.js**

```
if (fs.existsSync(__dirname + '/../Folder2/file2.js')) {
    console.log('Found file');
}
```

Comment: `__dirname + '../Folder2/file2.js'` gives me `directory/folder1../folder2/file2.js`. I need it to give me `directory/folder2/file2.js` instead

Comment: Updated my answer missed a slash before `../`. You can't directly get to that directory but you can check relative to your own directory that is relative to `file1.js`

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree file path use `string + string`. There is a way that use `path.join` is more safe and more right than string and [more information can see here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths).